# how did the domestic dog evolve and was the role humans played in its evolution justified?

Tags: artificial-selection

Humans have been selectively breeding dogs for a long time. Why do we do it? What are the positive and negative impacts of selective breeding and why do they occur?

I am writing an independent project on the subject >should selective breeding in dogs be allowed<, although I can think of many negatives to artificial selection, from a loss of genetic diversity to health problems for supposedly "pedigree dogs" I am finding it hard to find  positives other than for the development of breeds. I am especially looking for scientific research/papers/books on this theme of selective breeding in order to find  enough scientific information to write a balanced 3000 word essay. I hope this clears up the confusion surrounding the question, I was just looking for help, I did not realise my question would be graded!

Comment: What is your question? You are actually asking for a textbook. Please add some details to narrow down to the actual issue.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. `Why are we performing selective breeding in dogs?` is more a question of sociology and human culture than biology. `good and bad`. The terms "good" and "bad" are subject to personal interpretation and it is therefore impossible to give a scientific answer to this question. For these reasons, I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I think if '(both good and bad)' was removed it could be answerable. It does sound like a homework question to me (although of course that doesn't in itself mean it should be closed). I think the biggest problem is there's no evidence of research by the OP before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Selective breeding, or [artificial selection](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_30), by its very definition is the selection of desirable traits over less desirable ones. Individuals more like the desired phenotype are allowed to reproduce while others are not. Therefore, the reason a breed is selected in a certain way may be because of certain aesthetic characteristics, or speed, or hunting ability etc. For example, Schnauzers might have their beards/moustaches because for many generations breeders have wanted to accentuate this feature.

[image]

Artificial selection often causes problems because of [inbreeding](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/conservation_03) (an increase in homozygosity) and poorly imposed selection (only the desirable trait is considered, not other bad traits). This is why many dog breeds have [associated diseases or health problems](http://www.pets4homes.co.uk/pet-advice/inbreeding-in-dogs-problems-benefits-and-reasons.html).

---

[Image source](https://www.pinterest.com/tcarloss/schnauzer-love/)

Comment: The question is of poor quality and it is impossible to offer a good answer to it (IMO). You did a good job at offering some pieces of info that may help the OP though (+1)

Comment: there's obvious weaknesses in the question (even after my edits, I wanted to make the question clearer, but the issues of opinion remain because I didn't want to interfere with the OP's intent), there's really not much needed to answer such a question - *why do we select for desirable traits?* .. because selecting for undesirable traits would be stupid. Hopefully it gives the OP somewhere to start reading about it.